# Slim rowspan aggregation with Rails data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slim-lang

I'm using Rails with Slim.
I have this view with data (I hope that's ok to be filled with Russian):
[image]
So first column is filling with data I want to aggregate on. I want to see something like this:
[image]
But I really cannot figure out how can I do this.
Here is my Slim code:

```
  tbody
- @managers.each do |m|
  tr
    td= m.region
    td= m.name
    ...
```

And I've got hash with aggregated data like this:

```
{ region1: [row1, row2...],
  region2: [row3, row4...]}
```

But it's true problem to apply rowspan to first td only, and skip it for all other rows but first.
Please help.

Comment: Will there always be only two entries per region? Or can there be more?

Comment: @WesFoster can be more

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve it like this

```
tbody
- @managers.each do |region, data|
  - data.each_with_index do |m, index|
    tr          
      - if index.zero?
        td{rowspan: data.count}= m.region
      td= m.name
      ...
```

Comment: While tr is not closed, it will be only one row

Comment: It will close after every loop on `data`

Comment: it's not what i want. Rowspan attribute still require to break <tr> tag for new row

Comment: @aelaa changed the code as per your requirements. check now

Comment: it's ok now. Thanks!